# Set up and connect to local SQLEXPRESS database using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 r2 and adodbapi

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, adodbapi

For testing purposes, I am attempting to setup a SQL Server database on my local machine and connect to it using adodbapi in Python.  I used SQL Server Management Studio 2008 r2 to create a database and table.  I enabled the SQL Server Browser service, but I am still unable to connect using adodbapi.  Using this connections string:

```
adodbapi.connect(r'Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=COMPUTERNAME.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=userName; Password=password;')
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line
>   1, in    File
>   "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\adodbapi\adodbapi.py", line
>   307, in connect
>       raise OperationalError(e, "Error opening connection: " + connection_string) OperationalError: (com_error(-2147352567,
>   'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
>   Server', u'[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not
>   exist or access denied.', None, 0, -2147467259), None), 'Error opening
>   connection: Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=COMPUTERNAME.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial
>   Catalog=Test;User ID=userName; Password=password;')

Any insight into what I'm missing?

Comment: Why do you have `COMPUTERNAME.\SQLEXPRESS`? Did you try `COMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS` or `.\SQLEXPRESS` (one or the other, not *both*)?

Comment: I've been poking around for a few hours trying to find the answer and I came across a post that mentioned adding the dot before "\SQLEXPRESS".  With the dot added, when I attempt to connect, it takes a minute to think like it's actually doing something.  Without the dot, it just excepts stating that the server doesn't exist.  From what I understand, the dot means local.

Comment: And with `.\SQLEXPRESS` do you get a different error message after a minute, or the same error message? Are you sure the `SQLEXPRESS` service is running?

Comment: I get the same error message, but instead of taking a minute to think it immediately excepts.  I THINK the service is running... I started the SQL server browser service, but I'm very new to this so I may have missed a step.  Apart from SQL Server Browser it says that SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) is started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little more digging around and I ended up haphazardly stumbling on the answer.  I was missing "Integrated Security=SSPI" in my connection string and it turns out I didn't need the dot before "\SQLEXPRESS" in my data source.  Here's the connection string that worked for me:

```
adodbapi.connect(r'Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=COMPUTERNAME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=COMPUTERNAME\USERNAME; Password=PASSWORD;Integrated Security=SSPI')
```

Comment: If you specify a username and password explicitly, you shouldn't need the `Integrated Security` line. Can you confirm that your connection string does not work when you name the server correctly and you leave that attribute out?

Comment: I just ran it again with both connection strings and it did not work without the integrated security property defined.